# MLK Jr. quote about speaking out against anti-Semitism even if Jewish leaders say they don't need the help

Tags: quote-source, martin-luther-king

I remember some years ago listening to a recording of a speech by Martin Luther King Jr, in which he says something like:

> Even if Jewish leaders told me "No, we do not need your help fighting anti-Semitism," I would still speak out against anti-Semitism because it is wrong, it is evil, and it is unjust.

I could be mangling the quote, but that was the gist. I've googled as best I can but I can't figure out what speech it's from. I would appreciate any help in identifying the source.